# Signal - How to determine the fundamental frequency of a signal

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, signal-processing

I am only given one signal, $x(t)=\cos (200t)$, and I need to determine its fundamental angular frequency. But I'm a bit confused by the concept.

I only have 1 signal, but from Google I know that the fundamental frequency is the lcm of two signal's frequencies.

Comment: @Yves Daoust. The term "[angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency)" is used in physics to refer to the quantity $\ 2\pi\ $ times the inverse of the period (with units of radians per second rather than cycles per second).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: ok, I call that the *pulsation*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust according to the Euler's Law and polar form of signal, magnitude of x(t) is 1 and angular frequency $w$ is 200, should I just use this 200 as the fundamental frequency?

Comment: Read the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have picked up a couple of misunderstandings from your Google searches. The [fundamental frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency) of a periodic function is merely the inverse of its fundamental period (i.e. its shortest period).  It's the gcd (and normally the *lowest*) of the frequencies of the sinusoids appearing in the function's [Fourier expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).  The frequencies of all those sinusoids will be integral multiples of the fundamental frequency.

The fundamental frequency of the sum of just *two* sinusoids, the ratio of whose frequencies is a rational number, is the gcd (not the lcm) of their frequencies.

The fundamental frequency of a pure sinusoid (i.e. $\ \cos(at+b)\ $ or $\ \sin(at+b)\ $) is thus just its freqency, $\ \frac{a}{2\pi}\ $.  I've never heard the term "fundamental" applied to *angular* frequencies, but I would presume that "fundamental angular frequency" simply means $\ 2\pi\ $ times the fundamental frequency, in which case your answer of $200$ radians per unit time would be correct for the function $\ \cos(200t)\ $.